# Have enough connection but still getting Host 'x.x.x.x' blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using .net core 3.1 with mysql connector 8.0.21.
In mysql i have max_connection around 3000 and max_user_connection as 0 (unlimited)

In my connection pools setting in various application my total connection reserved are around 2800.
Still sometime i am getting this above error occasionally.
Any idea what could be the problem.

In my application there are two implementation for db access. one is dapper and other is old vanilla ado.net implementation.
Strange thing is when we queried the number of connection with all users via query

```
SELECT IFNULL(usr,'All Users') USER,IFNULL(hst,'All Hosts') HOST,COUNT(1) Connections
FROM
(
    SELECT USER usr,LEFT(HOST,LOCATE(':',HOST) - 1) hst
    FROM information_schema.processlist
    WHERE USER NOT IN ('system user','root')
) A GROUP BY usr,hst WITH ROLLUP;
```

Result is well under the limits of connection. nothing much in mysql error logs as well

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24761
Our server also have setup nagios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to third aprty monitoring tool nagios doing telnet on ip/port of mysql server
Problem was removed after removing the monitoring and doing alternative way for monitoring as mentioned in
https://serverfault.com/questions/578682/monit-mysql-server-blocked-because-of-too-many-bad-connections